# How to update oracle table in Python using data from another table

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am using the below code

```
SQL = 'UPDATE TBL1 T1 SET T1.COL1 = (SELECT T2.COL1 FROM TBL2 T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID)'
tmp_cursor=self.DB_conn.cursor()
tmp_cursor.execute(SQL)
```

I am not getting any error but the table is not getting updated.

Any suggestion on what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the to update using sqlplus, toad, sqldeveloper or any other oracle client?

Comment: Verify whether or not your program has committed the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/python-with-database-11g.html), you would need to commit the changes as a transaction for them to be available to other users and sessions:

> When you manipulate data in an Oracle Database (insert, update, or
>   delete data), the changed or new data is only available within your
>   database session until it is committed to the database.

So adding the following will do:

```
self.DB_conn.commit()
```

Comment: The explicit `commit()` causes a round-trip to the DB, which impacts performance scalability.  Review the [doc on using autocommit mode](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.autocommit), which has its place.